# Simple HTML DOM - How to get specific TR by contains TD text

Tags: php, parsing, html-parsing

I want only required row from below link by using simple HTML DOM:  http://projects.ednforum.com/salary/tspaydetailsget.php?id=1322733&year=2019-2020

May or June or July or any other.

How to show required month row only?

I used the below code but it's not working.

```
include('simple_html_dom.php');

$table = array();
$html2 = file_get_html ('http://projects.ednforum.com/salary/tspaydetailsget.php?id=1322733&year=2019-2020');
$html = str_get_html($html2);
$row = $html->find('table',0)->find('tr');
foreach($row as $data){
  if($data->innertext == $month)
  {
    $value = $data->innertext;
  }
}
echo $value;
```